# Why is hover effect not working in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have set a hover effect in my CSS, but it seems to be having no effect. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.button_link {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #ddf;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button_link#hover {
  color: orange;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div><a class="button_link" href="http://example.com">Return to example.com</a></div>
<div class="button_link">aa</div>
```

Comment: `.button_link:hover`

Comment: it should be `:hover`, not `#hover`

Comment: More information for pseudoclasses here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work as you expect it to simply because you've written your selector as:

```
.button_link#hover,
```

Which is the selector for an element with the class of `button_link` and an `id` of `hover`; whereas you want to target the element of class `button_link` with the `:hover` pseudo-class, therefore:

```
.button_link:hover
```

```css
.button_link {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #ddf;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button_link:hover {
  color: orange;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div><a class="button_link" href="http://example.com">Return to example.com</a></div>
<div class="button_link">aa</div>

</html>
```

Reference:

- [CSS Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/).

Answer (score 2):

`#` hover needs to be `:hover`

That should fix it

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to write:

```
.button_link:hover {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
        .button_link {
                display: inline-block;
                border: solid black 2px;
                border-radius: 15px;
                background-color: #ddf;
                padding: 10px;
                text-decoration: none;
        }

        .button_link:hover {
                color: orange;
                background-color: #fff;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div><a class="button_link" href="http://example.com">Return to example.com</a></div>
<div class="button_link">aa</div>
</html>
```

Hello, You should change **button_link#hover** to **button_link:hover**.
Happy coding!

Reference: **CSS Pseudo-classes**

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp